# Liquid Slider (Link to another page at end of scroll, rather than scroll back to first tab?) jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, slider

**jQuery / Javascript / PHP**

I am using the **[Liquid Slider](http://liquidslider.kevinbatdorf.com/)** as a pagination mechanism on a website, how I use it is I basically have it smoothly scroll through the pages left-right & vice versa.

What I'm trying to accomplish right now is: to have the dynamic arrows link to an external page at the end of the scroll (once it detects it is at its last page/tab), rather than to have it scroll back to where it first began.

Since such option variety is not originally supported from the author website, I am wondering if anyone from here would have an idea how to accomplish this?

A snippet of my dynamic arrows with their callback functions (functions not included):

```js
    $('#slider-id').liquidSlider({
        continuous:false,
        dynamicArrows:true,
        dynamicTabs: false,
        callbackFunction: function(){ drawLines() }
    });

    $('.liquid-nav-right-arrow').click(function(){
        simRefresh(), simRefresh2();
    });

    $('.liquid-nav-left-arrow').click(function(){
        simRefresh(), simRefresh2();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set conditionals based on the current panel (tab).

```
callbackFunction: function () {

var sliderObject = $.data( $('#slider-id)[0], 'liquidSlider');

if ( (sliderObject).currentTab === 4 ) {
  //turn off click event
  //update link
}
```

Then if you want to reset the events again, you can try `sliderObject.registerArrows()`, although I haven't tested this out.